# PostgreSQL 'with' and 'IN' query not liking each other

Tags: psql

I'm trying to write a PostgreSQL query using the WITH operator like so:

```sql
WITH team_people AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT person_id FROM team_person WHERE team_id = 558
)
SELECT p.first, p.email
FROM person p
WHERE ident IN team_people
```

I'm getting an error on the WHERE line that says "syntax error at or near team_people".

I'm using the "WITH" here because this will be a larger query in which I need to use the team_people set of numbers more than once.  What have I messed up on that syntax?

The server version is 9.1.18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be explicit in your column choice in the IN part by making a small inner SELECT statement:

```
... WHERE ident IN (SELECT person_id FROM team_people)
```

See for example the first snippet in the documentation: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-with.html

Your other option is to use a join:

```
... INNER JOIN team_people ON ident=person_id
```

The reason your original code doesn't work is that `team_people` isn't considered as a result containing a single column, but as a *temporary table* which happens to have a single column, and it's clear to see that the syntax you used won't work if team_people is a table.